# Use the same else block for nested try blocks in python

Tags: python, python-3.x, error-handling

I'm fitting a function to some data and some initial parameter values cause an overflow error. I want to catch it in my code, give it new initial parameters, and try again. My solution is to nest try except blocks.

```
try:
    foo(args1)
except:
    args2 = make_new_args()
    try:
        foo(args2)
    except:
        give_up_and_move_on()
    else:
        process_data()
else:
    process_data()
```

I was wondering if there's a way to eliminate one of the else clauses, since they're the same code.

Comment: It'll depend on what `give_up_and_move_on()` does. If it returns or raises an exception, you can remove the two `else`s and just have `process_data()` at the 0-indent level.

Comment: `process_data()` involves extracting the parameters out of a fit object and inserting them into an array. An overflow error prevents parameters from being generated, so if an overflow error is thrown twice, `process_data()` won't work and I have to use `give_up_and_move_on()` instead.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This looks a lot like some retry logic with modifications to the arguments; you could try this:

```
MAX_RETRIES = 2
for retries in range(MAX_RETRIES):
    try:
        foo(args)
    except:
        args = make_new_args()
    else:
        process_data()
        break

    if retries + 1 >= MAX_RETRIES:
        give_up_and_move_on()
```

Comment: Thanks, this is exactly what I was looking for! I made a teeny adjustment that clears it up: use an `else` block with the `for` loop instead of an `if` block.